# How do I list sub pages to the current page in Wordpress, genesis theme

Tags: php, wordpress, genesis

I want to list all closes children to the current page, not grand children or siblings, but when I try this, I get all pages.

```
function list_my_child_pages( $post ) {

    $list_p = array(
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order, post_title',
        'child_of' => $post->ID,
        'sort_order' => 'ASC'
    );

    $children = get_pages($list_p); 

    $result = "<ul>";
    foreach ( $children as $child )
    {
        $child_id = $child->ID;
        $url  = get_permalink( $child_id );
        $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($child_id, array(240, 240));
        $title= $child->post_title;

        $link = "<a href='$url'><div class='child_page_thumb'>$thumb</div><div class='child_page_title'>$title</div></a>";

        $result .= "<li>$link</li>";
    }

    $result .= "</ul>";

    echo $result;
}
```

To me it looks like it should not list siblings with this query, but it does. And how do I remove the grandchildren?

Answer (score 0):

I usually do that directly in the templates, here is my code :

```
<?php
// Showing the list of child pages
// Check if current page has children pages
$children = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID.'&parent='.$post->ID);

// if current page got children pages :
if (sizeof($children) > 0):                 
    $args = array(
        'post_status'       => ' publish',
        'post_type'         => 'page',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'post_parent'       => $post->ID,
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'orderby'           => 'date',
    );

    $parent = new WP_Query( $args );

    // Showing a list in the template
    if ( $parent->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <aside class="item-list">
            <?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); ?>
                <a class="item-from-list" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                    <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) {the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'alignleft'));} ?>
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <?php atm_content(20, true); ?>
                </a>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </aside>
    <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php endif;// end if sizeof($children) ?>
```

And if you don't want to get a list, you can store IDs for exemple in an array as following :

```
if ( $parent->have_posts() ) :
    $array = new Array();
    while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post();
        array_push($array, get_the_ID());
    endwhile;
endif;
```